# Gobblin JSON to Avro convert failed with not a Json Array error

Tags: gobblin

I'm new to Gobblin and trying to read JSON Kafka message and convert it to AVRO then store it in HDFS. My current job file is like a blow:

```
job.name=GobblinKafkaQuickStart
job.group=GobblinKafka
job.description=Gobblin quick start job for Kafka
job.lock.enabled=false

kafka.brokers=localhost:9092

source.class=org.apache.gobblin.source.extractor.extract.kafka.KafkaSimpleSource
extract.namespace=org.apache.gobblin.extract.kafka
converter.classes=org.apache.gobblin.converter.json.JsonStringToJsonIntermediateConverter, org.apache.gobblin.converter.avro.JsonIntermediateToAvroConverter


source.schema=[{"columnName":"name", "dataType":{"type": "string"}}, {"columnName":"city", "dataType":{"type": "string"}}, {"columnName":"age", "dataType":{"type": "integer"}}, {"columnName":"ubdated_at", "dataType":{"type": "string"}}]


writer.builder.class=org.apache.gobblin.writer.AvroDataWriterBuilder
extract.namespace=gobblin.source.extractor.filebased
gobblin.converter.schemaInjector.schema=SCHEMA
# writer.file.path.type=tablename
writer.destination.type=HDFS
writer.output.format=text

data.publisher.type=org.apache.gobblin.publisher.BaseDataPublisher

mr.job.max.mappers=1

metrics.reporting.file.enabled=true
metrics.log.dir=${gobblin.cluster.work.dir}/metrics
metrics.reporting.file.suffix=txt

bootstrap.with.offset=earliest
```

Example Kafka Massage: `{"age": 36, "city": "London", "name": "John", "ubdated_at": "2020-05-19"}`
However when I run this on standalone mode, getting bellow error.

```
ERROR [TaskExecutor-1] org.apache.gobblin.runtime.Task 551 - Task 
task_GobblinKafkaQuickStart_1589884160573_0 failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON
Array. at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106) at
org.apache.gobblin.converter.json.JsonStringToJsonIntermediateConverter.convertSchema(JsonStringToJsonIn
termediateConverter.java:71) at
org.apache.gobblin.converter.json.JsonStringToJsonIntermediateConverter.convertSchema(JsonStringToJsonIn
termediateConverter.java:48) at
org.apache.gobblin.instrumented.converter.InstrumentedConverterDecorator.convertSchema(InstrumentedConve
rterDecorator.java:79) at
org.apache.gobblin.runtime.MultiConverter.convertSchema(MultiConverter.java:76) at
org.apache.gobblin.runtime.Task.runSynchronousModel(Task.java:417) at
org.apache.gobblin.runtime.Task.run(Task.java:368) at org.apache.gobblin.runtime.TaskExecutor$TrackingTask.run(TaskExecutor.java:443) at
org.apache.gobblin.util.executors.MDCPropagatingRunnable.run(MDCPropagatingRunnable.java:39) at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your `gobblin.converter.schemaInjector.schema` property just says `SCHEMA`, and the library expects actual JSON schema at that place. You can either provide it, or reference the schema you defined above like this:

```
gobblin.converter.schemaInjector.schema='${source.schema}'
```

Comment: I have a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61998546/8089635, can you check this